# How to map domain model to persistent (ORM)?

Tags: typescript, orm, model, domain-driven-design, typeorm

I'm trying to figure out how to map my domain model to persistent or ORM (typeorm) entity.

I put this mappers in infrastructure layer as a separate class with static methods (toDomain(), toPersistence()), and do mapping in repository. But I have no idea how to control uuid generation, infrastructure is to late for uuid generation. Should I generate it in application layer?

I need know this uuid before object will be created in order to checking it after creation by querying it from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An excellent way to think about the problem is that *at no point in time can an aggregate or entity object be invalid*. If you agree that a unique `identifier` is mandatory to consider them valid, it follows that you have to generate the unique `ID` right at the time of instantiating the object.

It does not matter how you generate the identifier, though. It could be a UUID, a database sequence, or even an application method. What matters is that the `ID` is generated during initialization time and associated with the object.

You are on the right path with using `toDomain()`, `toPersistence()` methods in the infrastructure layer.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the domain is responsible to generate ids. That's usually solve the problems. I don't think that this is a problem from a DDD perspective.

Here is an example in Scala:

I use to have this kind of code in the domain model :

```
case class Person(id: PersonId, name: String)

case class PersonId(id: UUID)
object PersonId {
   def generate = PersonId(UUID.randomUUID)
}

// Then you can create a person:
val person = Person(PersonId.generate, "name")
```

`PersonId` is a value object. That allows to have a separation between the `UUID` and the `PersonId`.